# Create One Dimensional Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

How can I add field names to an array, when I do not know the size of the array?  In my two functions below, I am able to populate the table no problem, but when I try to create the array, it will only print the 1st record from the table.  What must I do in order to create the array with all values?

```
Function PopulateTable()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("MasterList")
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
  StrSQL = "INSERT INTO HoldTable (FieldList) VALUES ('" & fld.Name & "' );"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
Next
'Create array of all fld.Name Values
PopulateArray
End Function

Function PopulateArray()
Dim rstData    As DAO.Recordset
Dim v          As Variant
Dim cn         As Variant

Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select fieldlist from HoldTable")
v = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
For Each cn In v
  Debug.Print CStr(cn)
Next

End Function
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194427.aspx) (my emphasis), "GetRows returns a ***two-dimensional*** array."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ADODB.Connection and OpenSchema method to get a list of field names: [List database objects (tables, columns..) using ADO/ADOX](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_listdb/)

You'll need to use `rstData.MoveLast` and then `rstData.MoveFirst` to get an accurate `RecordCount`.

```
Function PopulateTable()
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MasterList")
    For Each fld In rs1.Fields
        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO HoldTable (FieldList) VALUES ('" & fld.Name & "' );"
        'Create array of all fld.Name Values
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
    Next
    PopulateArray
End Function

Function PopulateArray()
    Dim rstData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim cn As Variant

    Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select fieldlist FROM HoldTable")
    rstData.MoveLast
    rstData.MoveFirst
    v = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
    For Each cn In v
        Debug.Print CStr(cn)
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Excellent, that was what I needed.  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights Thank you for accepting my answer..again. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would create a dynamic array.
I would loop through the data and within each iteration increment the size of the array and then set the value to the newly incremented array

```
Dim arraySize as Integer
Dim dynArray() As string
arraySize = -1 ' set to -1 so when you first increment the size by one it will start at index 0

' Iterating through rstData variable
for each fld in rstData.fields
   arraySize = arraySize + 1
   redim preserve dynArray(arraySize) as String
   dynArray(sz) = fld ' not sure if can set it to fld directly or if need to access the value property of fld
next
' End of iterating through
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a "normal" variable and assign an empty array to it:

```
Dim v : v = Array()
```

Then you can redim it:

```
ReDim Preserve v(rstData.RecordCount)
```

Comment: If I add the ReDim Preserve statement under my Debug.Print statement, I get an error of 'The array is fixed or temporarily locked'

Comment: but did you also change the declaration of v to Dim v() or  Dim v : v = Array()?